# \foreach doesn't compose with my string-splitting command

Tags: foreach, strings, arguments

I wrote `\myfunc` which splits a colon-delimited string into two parts. It works, in and of itself, as does a simple `\foreach` over comma-separated colon-delimited strings.

But if I try to call `\myfunc` from within the `\foreach`, I get a `runaway argument` error.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\def\myfunc#1{\myfuncdoit#1\relax}
\def\myfuncdoit#1:#2\relax{ First: (#1), Second: (#2) }

\myfunc{foo bar:int * const}

\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}{ (\p) }

\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}{ (\myfunc{\p}) } % <<<----- ERROR

\end{document}
```

I expected the last `\foreach` to produce

```
( First: (foo), Second: (int) )
( First: (bar), Second: (float) )
( First: (baz), Second: (bool) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand `\p` before `\myfunc` acts.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\def\myfunc#1{\myfuncdoit#1\relax}
\def\myfuncdoit#1:#2\relax{ First: (#1), Second: (#2) }

\myfunc{foo bar:int * const}

\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}{ (\p) }

\foreach \p in {foo:int,bar:float,baz:bool}{ (\expandafter\myfunc\expandafter{\p}) }

\end{document}
```

Otherwise, use more powerful methods.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfunc}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}{%
  \myfuncsplit#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myfuncsplit}{mm}{%
  First: (#1), Second: (#2)%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cycle}{ m +m }
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cycle{foo:int, bar:float, baz:bool}{\myfunc{#1}\par}

\end{document}
```

Note that spaces around commas in the list are trimmed off. In the second argument to `\cycle`, you use `#1` to represent the current item in the comma separated list.

[image]